# Blank XML request stream for SOAP web service call from VB6 to C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, service, vb6, web

I have an issue calling a C# web service from a VB6 windows program and I'm hoping for some help.

The issue is that the request.stream that the web service reads is blank and therefore returns and error that the root node is not present.

The VB6 code that calls the service is:

```vb
    Private Sub CmdHTTPPost_Click()
    Dim http As WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
    Dim strURL As String, strFormData As String
    Dim pvtPartNo As String
    Text1.Text = ""

    strFormData = TxtVoucherNo.Text
    strURL = "http://proof.another.co.uk/admin/stockupdate.asmx"
    http = New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
    ' Open an HTTP connection.
    http.SetTimeouts(20 * 1000, 20 * 1000, 20 * 1000, 20 * 1000)
    http.Open("POST", strURL, False)

    http.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=uft-8")

    http.ResponseStream()
    http.Send(strFormData)
    http.WaitForResponse()
    Text1.Text = http.ResponseText
    http = Nothing

End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
    TxtVoucherNo.Text = TestWebPost()
End Sub
Public Function createHeaderXML(pvtBranchNo As String, pvtRef As String) As String
    createHeaderXML = "<?xml version =" & """" & "1.0" & """" & " ?>" & _
    "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=" & """" & "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" & """" & " xmlns:xsd=" & """" & "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" & """" & " xmlns:soap=" & """" & "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" & """" & ">" & _
    "<soap:Body>" & _
    "<UpdateStock xmlns=" & """" & "http://www.another.co.uk.admin.stockupdate/" & """" & "/>" & _
    "<txn>" & _
    "<branch>" & pvtBranchNo & "</branch>" & _
    "<receipt>" & pvtRef & "</receipt>"


    '"<txn xmlns:soap=" & """" & "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" & """" & " xmlns:xsi=" & """" & "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" & """" & " xmlns:xsd=" & """" & "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" & """>" & _
    '"<!--! " & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:nn:ss") & " -->" & _
    '"<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=" & """" & "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" & """" & " xmlns:xsd=" & """" & "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" & """" & " xmlns:soap=" & """" & "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" & """" & ">" & _
    '"<soap:Body>" & _
    '"<UpdateStock xmlns=" & """" & "http://www.another.co.uk.admin.stockupdate/" & """" & "/>"
End Function

Public Function createEndXML()
    createEndXML = "</txn>" & _
    "</soap:Body>" & _
    "</soap:Envelope>"

End Function
Public Function createPartXML(pvtPartNo As String, pvtStatus As String, pvtQuantity As String) As String

    createPartXML = "<orderline>" & _
    "<partno>" & pvtPartNo & "</partno>" & _
    "<quantity>" & pvtQuantity & "</quantity>" & _
    "<condition>" & pvtStatus & "</condition>" & _
    "</orderline>"
End Function

Public Function TestWebPost() As String

    Dim testString As String

    testString = createHeaderXML("1", "111554") + createPartXML("xt801", "1", "2") + createPartXML("xt1200", "1", "1") + createEndXML()

    TestWebPost = testString
End Function
```

The web service code is this:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://www.another.co.uk.admin.stockupdate/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class stockupdate : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    public string UpdateStock()
    {
        Boolean complete = false;
        int errorPlace = 0;
        string strmContents = "";
        XmlNode txn = null;
        string postMessage = ""; 
        try
        {
            ArrayList orderlines = new ArrayList();
            int branch = 0;
            Int64 receipt = 0;

            errorPlace++;  // = 1

            using (System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream))
            {
                while (reader.Peek() >= 0)
                {
                    strmContents += reader.ReadLine();
                }
            }

            // set testing content for xml..
            // strmContents = "<?xml version =\"1.0\" ?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><soap:Body><UpdateStock xmlns=\"http://www.another.co.uk.admin.stockupdate/\"/><txn><branch>1</branch><receipt>111554</receipt><orderline><partno>xt801</partno><quantity>2</quantity><condition>1</condition></orderline><orderline><partno>xt1200</partno><quantity>1</quantity><condition>1</condition></orderline></txn></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>";

            postMessage += strmContents;

            errorPlace++; // = 2

            XmlDocument thisXmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

            thisXmlDoc.LoadXml(strmContents);
            XmlNamespaceManager nsmanager = new XmlNamespaceManager(thisXmlDoc.NameTable);
            nsmanager.AddNamespace("soap", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");

            //txn = thisXmlDoc.DocumentElement;

            errorPlace++; // = 3

            // Get Branch
            XmlNode bchNode = thisXmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/txn/branch", nsmanager);
            branch = Convert.ToInt32(bchNode.InnerText);

            errorPlace++; // = 4

            XmlNode rcptNode = thisXmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/txn/receipt", nsmanager);
            receipt = Convert.ToInt32(rcptNode.InnerText);

            errorPlace++; // = 5

            //get Companies
            XmlNodeList olItems = thisXmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("orderline");
            foreach (XmlNode orderline in olItems)
            {
                try
                {
                    XmlNode partNo = orderline.SelectSingleNode("partno");
                    XmlNode quantity = orderline.SelectSingleNode("quantity");
                    XmlNode condition = orderline.SelectSingleNode("condition");
                    string[] item = new string[3] { partNo.InnerText, quantity.InnerText, condition.InnerText };
                    orderlines.Add(item);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    postMessage = ex.Message;
                }
            }

            errorPlace++; // = 6

            string strItems = "";
            string strQuantities = "";

            try
            {
                // Update stock numbers            
                foreach (string[] orderItem in orderlines)
                {
                    string sql = "";
                    // Get stockitem_id
                    using (SqlConnection stockConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalSqlServer"].ConnectionString))
                    {
                        errorPlace++; // = 7

                        stockConn.Open();

                        sql = "SELECT stockitem_id FROM tbl_stockitem WHERE stockitem_number LIKE '" + orderItem[0] + "'";
                        SqlCommand idCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, stockConn);
                        int thisStockitemId = Convert.ToInt32(idCommand.ExecuteScalar());
                        if (thisStockitemId > 0)
                        {
                            if (Convert.ToInt16(orderItem[2]) == 1)
                            {
                                sql = "UPDATE tbl_storestockitemxref SET stockitem_numbernew = stockitem_numbernew - " + orderItem[1] + " WHERE stockitem_id = " + thisStockitemId + " AND store_id = " + branch;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                sql = "UPDATE tbl_storestockitemxref SET stockitem_numberused = stockitem_numberused - " + orderItem[1] + " WHERE stockitem_id = " + thisStockitemId + " AND store_id = " + branch;
                            }
                            SqlCommand updateCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, stockConn);
                            updateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                            if (!strItems.Equals(""))
                            {
                                strItems += "|" + orderItem[0];
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                strItems += orderItem[0];
                            }

                            if (!strQuantities.Equals(""))
                            {
                                strQuantities += "|" + orderItem[1];
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                strQuantities += orderItem[1];
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Exception ex = new Exception("Couldn't find part number " + orderItem[0] + "; ");
                            throw ex;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                postMessage += ex.Message;
            }


            // Register complete on receipt table
            try
            {
                errorPlace++; // = 8

                using (SqlConnection receiptConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalSqlServer"].ConnectionString))
                {
                    receiptConn.Open();
                    string sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_livestockreceipts (receipt_no, receipt_branch, receipt_message, receipt_items, receipt_quantities) VALUES (" + receipt + ", " + branch + ", '" + postMessage + "', '" + strItems + "', '" + strQuantities + "')";
                    SqlCommand receiptCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, receiptConn);
                    receiptCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                complete = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                postMessage += ex.Message;
                // do nothing
                anotherDAL.emails emailFuncs = new anotherDAL.emails();
                string emailMsg;
                emailMsg = "<p>Error on the INSERT RECEIPT function for live updates</p>";
                emailMsg += "<p>" + ex.Message + "</p>";
                emailFuncs.sendEmail("another <websales@another.co.uk>", "benjamin@another.co.uk", "Live stock update error!", "Oh, Bugger!", "", "<br/><br/>" + emailMsg + "<br/><br/>");
                complete = false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            postMessage += ex.Message;
            // do nothing
            anotherDAL.emails emailFuncs = new anotherDAL.emails();
            string emailMsg;
            emailMsg = "<p>Error on function for live updates</p>";
            emailMsg += "<p>" + ex.Message + "</p>";
            emailFuncs.sendEmail("another <websales@another.co.uk>", "benjamin@another.co.uk", "Live stock update error!", "Oh, Bugger!", "", "<br/><br/>" + emailMsg + "<br/><br/>");
            complete = false;
        }

        if (complete)
        {
            return "Success" + "; error = " + errorPlace.ToString() + "<br /><br />" + postMessage + "<br /><br />Input: " + strmContents; 
        }
        else
        {
            return "Fail" + "; error = " + errorPlace.ToString() + "<br /><br />" + postMessage + "<br /><br />Input: " + strmContents; 
        }
    }
}
```

I have a test C# code that calls the web service and works fine:

```
    protected void StockUpdateService(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {

            Uri address = new Uri("http://proof.another.co.uk/admin/stockupdate.asmx/UpdateStock");  //Uri address = new Uri("http://localhost:300/admin/stockupdate.asmx/UpdateStock"); // 

            // Create the web request  
            HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(address) as HttpWebRequest;

            // Set type to POST  
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=utf-8";


            // Set content of request
            // string xmlRequest = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?><txn><branch>1</branch><receipt>111554</receipt><orderline><partno>xt801</partno><quantity>2</quantity><condition>1</condition></orderline><orderline><partno>xt1200</partno><quantity>1</quantity><condition>1</condition></orderline></txn>";
            // string xmlRequest = "<?xml version =\"1.0\" ?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><soap:Body><UpdateStock xmlns=\"http://www.another.co.uk.admin.stockupdate/\"/><txn><branch>1</branch><receipt>111554</receipt><orderline><partno>xt801</partno><quantity>2</quantity><condition>1</condition></orderline><orderline><partno>xt1200</partno><quantity>1</quantity><condition>1</condition></orderline></txn></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>";
            string xmlRequest = "Blah";

            StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
            data.Append(xmlRequest);

            // Create a byte array of the data we want to send  
            byte[] byteData = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data.ToString());

            // Set the content length in the request headers  
            request.ContentLength = byteData.Length;

            // Write data  
            using (Stream postStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                postStream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length);
            }

            // Get response  
            using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                // Get the response stream  
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

                // Console application output  
                Response.Write(reader.ReadToEnd());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Any help as to how to get the web service to read the http request body/stream from the VB call would be helpful.

Comment: Have you tried sniffing the messages with Fiddler and comparing the differences?

Comment: I have a response that shows me what is being read in and with the VB6 call the HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream is blank; where as with the c# call the HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream has the posted XML as expected.

Comment: It might be simpler to use C# to create a COM component that calls the service (using WCF, of course), then let the VB6 application consume the COM component.

Comment: What are you getting back from the Send method. Have you checked the WinHttpRequest.Status?

Comment: Beaner - The web service replies as it should with a FAIL and the error that is caught in the service.  It fails on the fact that it can't find the root element on the XML as there is none there - the inputstream is blank.

Comment: John Saunders - Not sure how to do that one?  Any pointers to tutorials?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in the VB6 code:

```
charset=uft-8
```

vs

```
charset=utf-8
```

EDIT1:

Aren't you asking for a response stream before you send your POST content

```
http.ResponseStream()     
http.Send(strFormData)
```

Try inverting these so you send first

Comment: @BenDrury Any success with sending the data before fetching the response stream?